# How to save data of a game

Tags: ios, swift, save

I am trying to make a simple game for IOS using xcode and swift 2. The game I would like to make is similar to "a dark room", so it does not have complicated graphic or anything really difficult.

I was not able to find \ understand how to save (and then load) the data of the progress of the game, which would include my clickcounts, arrays, textview, and some variables for the inventory. I would like to have a button "save" and a button "load".

I would also like to add that the game I am making is with the setting "simple view application" of xcode.

I am new to programming, please be detailed :)

Answer (score 1):

For a basic game you might get away with NSUserDefaults. Just create a plist file (i.e. Defaults.plist) with your settings - i.e. score, rounds, etc. and then use something like the code below to read register these defaults in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in your AppDelegate.

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let prefs = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: prefs!)
    defaults.setObject(dict, forKey: "defaults")                
    defaults.registerDefaults(dict as! [String : AnyObject])  
    defaults.synchronize()
```

Later you can read and set your defaults throughout your app by accessing:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

You would retrieve a value like so:

```
let score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("score")
```

and set it this way:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "score")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I am not quite sure I understand, unfortunately I do not have much experience with programming. what do you mean by creating it with my settings? how do i make a new plist file? and how do i use those codes with a button "save"?

Comment: You create your plist (Property List) file as new document in Xcode (cmd-N once you have opened your project). I added a screenshot to my original post. The property list allows you to enter all sorts of values in that you can use as starting point and edit in your app.