# How to show custom cells using NSUserDefaults in UITableView after killing/quitting application, Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I have created a task app, where in one viewcontroller (AddPlan.swift) I input 4 strings and those 4 strings are then saved into a tableview inside another viewcontroller(ViewController.swift). Everything is working to plan, however I want the tableview cells that already have been created, to be presented even if I kill the app. I have looked at tutorials, however no tutorials show how to save the cells if it is a custom cell. I do know you can use NSUserDefaults but there has been no luck for me.

Here is a look at my AddPlan.swift that is related to my problem

```
class addPlan: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


var time: Int = 6


@IBOutlet var txt: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var Complete: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet var btn7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btn6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var txt3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txt2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txt1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Button02: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {



    self.txt.delegate = self;
    self.txt1.delegate = self;
    self.txt2.delegate = self;
    self.txt3.delegate = self;





}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}


@IBAction func ClickedforSelection(sender: AnyObject) {
    taskMgr.addTask(txt.text!, desc: txt1.text!, date: txt2.text!, clas: txt3!.text!)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    txt.text = ""
    txt1.text = ""
    txt2.text = ""
    txt3.text = ""
```

Here is my ViewController.swift that is related to my problem

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        taskMgr.tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(taskMgr, forKey: "list")
        tbl?.reloadData();
    }


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tbl?.reloadData();
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    if (self.resultSearchController.active)
    {
        return self.filteredAppleProducts.count
    }
    else
    {
        return taskMgr.tasks.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableView

        cell.lbl.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.lbl2.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc
        cell.lbl4.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].date
        cell.lbl3.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].clas

        return cell

}
```

Here is my ViewController.swift file's ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.\
    text.enabled = false


    self.tbl?.delegate = self
    self.tbl?.dataSource = self

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("list") != nil {




     }


    tbl!.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    tbl!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239 / 255.0, green: 239 / 255.0, blue: 239 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

My TaskMgr.tasks comes from this file..

```
import UIKit

var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct task{
  var name = "Un-Named"
  var desc = "Un-Described"
  var date = "Un-Described"
  var clas = "Un-Described"

}

class TaskManager: NSObject {

var tasks = [task]()

func addTask(name: String, desc: String, date: String, clas: String){
    tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc, date: date, clas: clas))
  }
}
```

To clarify once more, my app has 2 viewcontrollers where one (AddPlan.swift) has 4 UITextFeilds as well as one button. I input words in that textfield, and if I press the button, those words are then transferred to a UITableView in another viewcontroller (ViewController.swift). The words are then showed in a cell. What I want to know is how code the cells so that if I quit/kill the app, they would still be showed if I re-open the application.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You said "I would like the text in the cell, such as lbl,lbl1,lbl2,lbl3 to be saved even if I kill the application."

You are thinking about this wrong. Table view cells are view objects in the MVC design pattern. They display information to the user and interact with user. They don't store information. Data is stored in the model (often an array.) In your case it looks like `taskMgr.tasks` contains the array of data you are displaying to your table view. If the user alters the data in the cell then you should immediately save those changes, either directly to `taskMgr.tasks[row]`, or to some temporary array of changes so that you can support undo.

In any case, what you need to figure out is how to save your model data. To help you with that you'll need to explain more about your model.

I see that you opened a duplicate question with more information. Don't do that. Edit your original question to provide information about your model, how it's created, and whatever you've currently done to load/save that model data.

Note that user defaults might not be a good choice. It's intended for saving small amounts of simple data. It's not a good idea to store large amounts of volatile data. Another form of storage might be a better choice, but you haven't given us enough information to make a recommendation.

Comment: By Model, do you mean using CoreData? Also, I would just like the cells of the UITableView to be saved even if I kill the app, do you have any recommendations of how to do this in swift?

Comment: The model is a concept. It is whatever logical construct in your app that is responsible for holding your application data. Sometimes the model is just in memory. Sometimes it's saved to disk, using Core Data, user defaults, or some other method. Cells DO NOT HOLD DATA. THEY PRESENT IT. The phrase "I would just like the cells of the UITableView to be saved..." indicates that you are thinking about this wrong. Cells do not hold data.

Comment: I see, alright I edited it, however I still need a way to present the cells even if I kill the app, because if I kill the app, the cells are not showing and I want it to be.

Comment: You need to explain that. Where does your taskMgr.tasks data structure come from? How is it populated originally? User Entry? Are you saying that if the user enters data, then you kill the app, the users input is lost? You need to provide a lot more information (edit your question, don't do it in comments.)

Comment: Please check the edit above, all in all, thank you so far for helping me, much appreciated :)

Comment: I did find a solution and will post it in a while

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided there are no calls to save any information which may be the reason for your issue. Typically you would save data to NSUserDefaults with 
something like:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name, forKey: "taskName")
```

Maybe take a look at [How to save data of a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621433/how-to-save-data-of-a-game/) for some help with NSUserDefaults.

Comment: So if I were to use the line of code you provided, where would I put it exactly?

Comment: As well as how would I call it so that it would save the data

Comment: Can you please give more information on how to do this? As well as check the edit above.